# Запуск приложения Java

Tags: java

Начал изучать java. Разобрался как написать HelloWorld. Но не могу понять, как запустить с использованием командной строки. Расскажите, как запускать приложение в Windows 7 через консоль. Приложение сохранено в файле HelloWorld.java.

Comment: Нашел проблему  
Все оказалось проще, не установлен был JRE  
Так что то, что программа работает через Eclipce не дает гарантии, что все будет нормально в итоге.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала в консоли переходите в папку с файлом HelloWorld.java и пишете следующие строки.

```
javac HelloWorld.java  
java HelloWorld
```

Comment: А если не настроены переменные?  Javac не сработает)))

Comment: если не настроены то нужно настроить. вот нашел в интернете инструкцию. Заходим в свойства моего компьютера(Win+Break) -> Дополнительно -> Переменные среды.В переменную path через точку с запятой выставляем путь к папке JDK/bin.Создаем переменную JAVA_HOME и записываем путь к JDK

Comment: А если в Linux то как PATH прописать?

Comment: все зависит от того какой у вас шелл

Comment: > А если в Linux то как PATH прописать?

В Linux обычно таких проблем нету. А если есть, то просто поместите ссылки на java и javac в папку usr/bin.

Comment: ещё на javaws через alternativs